# Access of shared variable throws object reference error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a shared variable in a Form.

```
Public Class FormHome
      Public Shared db_config As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

When I try to access this variable from another form,

```
FormHome.db_config.ContainsKey("m")
```

It works fine in my system (Windows 7). But I get object reference error (System.NullReferenceException) in Windows XP (client system) in exactly that line.

In both places, .NET 4.0 framework (Version - 4.0.30319.18034) is used by the application. Seems weird. What causes this error?

Comment: are you using the variable without definition ?
ex. when in you code you say 'db_config = new Dictionary(Of String, String)()' ?

Comment: In a login form, before calling FormHome.show(), I initialize this variable and populate its values. Then when I try to access it from a different new form, I get that error

Comment: well, i cant actually imagine the problem. while doing some search if found this article which popped the idea of different 4.0.X versions of.Net Framework.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600211

Comment: in above Link, Issue #10:
System.NullReferenceExcption- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @MuhammadOmar I read that link. It is not related to what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
Public Shared db_config As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

only *declares a variable* (`db_config`) of the requested type. It does not *create an object* of that type.

Before you create the object, `db_config` is still null, and thus attempting to access it will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

To create an object, you need to use the `New` keyword. For example:

```
db_config = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
```

You need to make sure that this object creation happens *before* the first attempt is made to access the variable's value. Because you're using a static (`Shared`) variable, doing it in the class's instance constructor may be too late. The regular instance constructor only gets executed when you create an instance of the object.

Therefore, I recommend doing it in the object's static constructor. As [the language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711965.aspx) explains in more detail, the static constructor of a class is guaranteed to have been executed by the runtime by the time that any of the static members of that class is accessed.

Add the following code to your `FormHome` class:

```
Shared Sub New()
    db_config = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
End Sub
```